# Reinstalling Matplotlib on Mac

Tags: macos, matplotlib, libpng, freetype

I upgraded packages and broke my matplotlib installation. Now when I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so, 2):       
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

To fix this, I uninstalled freetype and libpng using `brew`. Specifically, I used `brew uninstall freetype && brew cleanup && brew install freetype` and the same commands with `libpng`.
The I reinstalled matplotlib (`pip uninstall matplotlib`, then `pip install matplotlib`).

This did not fix it, and I don't know what the next step is to be able to have a working matplotlib (`.pyplot`) installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a very similar issue running OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks) and trying to get IPython 2.0 working.  Here is what I did to fix it.

**Step #1: Uninstall matplotlib**:

```
$ pip uninstall matplotlib
```

**Step #2: Use libpng v1.5.17**:

```
$ brew update
$ cd `brew --prefix` (this brought me to /usr/local)
$ brew versions libpng
$ git checkout c22afb9 Library/Formula/libpng.rb (this gets version 1.5.17)
$ brew install libpng
$ brew switch libpng 1.5.17
$ git checkout -- Library/Formula/libpng.rb
```

**Step #3: Use freetype v2.5.0.1**:

```
$ cd `brew --prefix` (this brought me to /usr/local)
$ brew versions freetype
$ git checkout 6314fdb Library/Formula/freetype.rb (this gets version 2.5.0.1)
$ brew install freetype
$ brew switch freetype 2.5.0.1
$ git checkout -- Library/Formula/freetype.rb
```

**Step #4: Re-install matplotlib**:

```
$ CFLAGS="-I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/X11/include/freetype2" pip install matplotlib
```

NOTE: You may need to adjust your CFLAGS to match where you have the freetype headers installed (but I'm assuming if you had matplotlib installed earlier, you know how to re-install it again)

Now I have a working matplotlib:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar  3 2014, 15:04:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>>
```

It has fixed the matplotlib issue I was having in IPython.

I hope this works for you too.

Comment: The `brew versions` command is outdated. What's the updated command?

Answer (score 4):

I have met the same problem. Thanks to [**galvanist's blog**](http://galvanist.com/post/50664743492/matplotlib-pip-homebrew-problems), the following solution works well for me. The `sudo` before `pip` can be removed if you have the permisson (for example, using the virtualenv).

```
# possibly optional for you
sudo pip uninstall matplotlib

# possibly optional for you
sudo rm -rf /tmp/pip-build-root/

brew reinstall libpng --universal

brew reinstall freetype --universal

sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a recommendation.

I had the same problem like you. I had installed Anaconda on OSX in advanced. But my matplotlib seems corrupted anyway. So I remove matplotlib and reinstall it with pip. The the problem appeared.

In my case, Frederic's solution can resolve `image not found` problem. But another problem shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 97, in <module>
  _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup 
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])   
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 21, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
  ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so, 2): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so
```

My final solution is reinstall matplotlib with `conda install matplotlib`. Then all problems resolved.

Answer (score 0):

for those who got the `brew versions` error, it is an obsolete command. I got it working by going straight to to `brew install libpng` and `brew install freetype`.

Install brew:
`$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

```
$ cd `brew --prefix` (this brought me to /usr/local)
$ brew install libpng
$ brew install freetype
$ easy_install matplotlib
```

After I did that, I relaunched Spyder and the `matploblib` error went away

Answer (score 0):

for those met the same issue on Spyder. You might use `conda install libpng` to address issue.